# Set limit on number of files user can upload in Liferay Documents and Media?

Tags: liferay

I've seen in liferay where we can specify the upload size of a file

```
dl.file.max.size=
```

But I haven't found a way to specify how to limit the number of files a user (or community) can upload. Obviously, we don't want a user or community upload massive amounts of files and filling up our shared drive. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think anything like this is present as of now. But this could be a good feature to add.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such quota - that's why you didn't find it. However, you are able to extend Liferay to contain and honor a quota. It has been demonstrated [with this app](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/64917410) - source code is linked and you might be able to take it as the basis for building your number-of-files-quota. It also doesn't seem to take the number of files into account, but it keeps an eye over the volume stored already and should be easy to extend.

I'm assuming that the spanish user group would happily accept pullrequests if you have a good extension to this plugin.